# Consulta or eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy haciendo una consulta `eloquent` para traer los datos que esten en una fecha o en otra, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
$eneP= tbl_calibracion::where('cal_usu_id',$onlyId)
    ->whereDate('cal_proximaCalibracion','=','2019-01-01 00:00:00')
    ->orWhere('cal_proximaCalibracion','=','2020-01-01 00:00:00')
    ->count();
```

El problema es que me trae 34 registros cuando deberia de traer 4, hice la consulta en `mysql` y me funciono de esta manera:

```
SELECT count(cal_id)as id FROM `tbl_calibracion` WHERE cal_usu_id='7' and (cal_proximaCalibracion='2019-01-01 00:00:00' or cal_proximaCalibracion='2020-01-01 00:00:00')
```

En `MySQL` me salian 34 registros si no ponia los parentesis pero ese `error` como lo puedo solucionar con eloquent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar un where con function para generar los paréntesis

```
$eneP= tbl_calibracion::where('cal_usu_id',$onlyId)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereDate('cal_proximaCalibracion','=','2019-01-01 00:00:00')
        ->orWhere('cal_proximaCalibracion','=','2020-01-01 00:00:00');
    })->count();
```

Comment: Gracias funciona, por cierto te falto el `;` en la linea del `orWhere`